# How do I get flash to run in a separate instance for each tab (Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, flash

I remember this used to be possible. You could have Flash run in a separate sandboxed instance for each tab. I have looked across the great interweb and cannot figure out how to do this though?

It was usefull because it caused flash running on one page to not "stagger" the flash running on another page, and also because it kept one Flash crash from crashing Flash in all open tabs.

Comment: I don't think so... I think that Internet Explorer is the only browser to use a new instance of flash for each tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an option to " flash running on one page to not "stagger" the flash running on another page ".

"To reduce exposure to attack, plugins are run in separate processes that communicate with the renderer, itself operating at "very low privileges" in dedicated per-tab processes." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome

"What goes in each process? .. Browser.. Renderers.. Plugins" Section 2 http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html

"Google Chrome gave each tab and plug-in its own process to work" you can Change the tab process model with command command line parameters http://www.thinkdigit.com/Features/Change-how-Google-Chrome-manages-processes_6077.html

"all Flash movies run in the same process, regardless of which sites or tabs they appear in." https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/process-models

Answer (score -1):

With Google Chrome this may be not the case.

Google Chrome's flash runs in a separate process for each instance. Don't open too many tabs, but you can multitask.

Flash running in separate tabs probably have much less priority than flash running in the current time.

To test this for yourself, go to http://www.online-stopwatch.com/ in two tabs. If you start both of them (flash applications) they will run and either will not stop if you are in the other tab.